# Passing an object to a REST Web Service using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have a simple WS that is a `@PUT` and takes in an object

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @PUT
    @Path("{nid}"}
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public WolResponse callWol(@PathParam("nid") WolRequest nid) {
        WolResponse response = new WolResponse();
        response.setResult(result);
        response.setMessage(nid.getId());

        return response;
    }
```

and my client side code is...

```
WebResource wr = client.resource(myurl);
WolResponse resp = wr.accept("application/xml").put(WolResponse.class, wolRequest);
```

I am trying to pass an instance of `WolRequest` into the `@PUT` Webservice. I am constantly getting 405 errors trying to do this..

How can I pass an object from the client to the server via Jersey ? Do I use a query param or the request ?

Both my POJOs (`WolRequest` and `WolResponse`) have the `XMlRootElement` tag defined so i can produce and consume xml..

Comment: 405 is "method not allowed". Do you need to configure your web server to allow PUT?

Answer (score 1):

I think the usage of the `@PathParam` is not correct here. A `@PathParam` is can basically be a `String` (see its javadoc for more info).

You can

1. use the `@PathParam` as a String parameter or
2. don't define WolRequest as a @PathParam.

The first approach:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @PUT
    @Path("{nid}")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public WolResponse callWol(@PathParam("nid") String nid) {
        WolResponse response = new WolResponse();
        response.setResult(result);
        response.setMessage(nid);

        return response;
    }
```

This will accept urls like: "text/12", 12 will then be the String nid. It doesn't look like this will help what you are trying to do.

The second approach:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public WolResponse callWol(WolRequest nid) {
        WolResponse response = new WolResponse();
        response.setResult(result);
        response.setMessage(nid.getId());

        return response;
    }
```

Your client code can be like you specified, only the url for PUT is: "test". Perhaps you need a combination of both one `@PathParam` for your id and one "normal" parameter to get your request data.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

As per the code sample of method putTodo of class TodoResource ,
your code should be like this.

```
@Path("test")
public class Test{

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public WolResponse callWol(JAXBElement<WolRequest> nid) {
        WolResponse response = new WolResponse();
        response.setResult(result);
        response.setMessage(nid.getValue().getId());

        return response;
   }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response callWol(WolRequest nid) {
     WolResponse response = new WolResponse();
     response.setResult(result);
     response.setMessage(nid.getValue().getId());
     return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(response).build();
}
```

You can try @PUT instead of @Post as well. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I solved in **3 Steps** with **Jackson** in Netbeans/Glashfish btw.

1)Requirements :

some of the Jars I used :

```
 commons-codec-1.10.jar
 commons-logging-1.2.jar
 log4j-1.2.17.jar
 httpcore-4.4.4.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.4.jar
 avalon-logkit-2.2.1.jar
 javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-b01.jar
 httpclient-4.5.1.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.4.jar
 jackson-databind-2.7.0-rc1.jar
 jackson-annotations-2.7.0-rc1.jar
 jackson-core-2.7.0-rc1.jar
```

If I missed any of the jar above , you can download from Maven here **http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

2)Java Class where you send your Post.
First ,Convert with Jackson the Entity User to Json and then send it to your Rest Class.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import ht.gouv.mtptc.siiv.model.seguridad.Usuario;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class PostRest {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

         // 1. create HttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost 
        = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8083/i360/rest/seguridad/obtenerEntidad");


        String json = "";
        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setId(99L);

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", u.getId());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        //json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
         //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         //json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       json = mapper.writeValueAsString(u);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");


        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        //inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

}


}
```

3)Java Class Rest where you want to receive the Entity JPA/Hibernate .
Here with your MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON you recieve the Entity in this way :

> ""id":**99**,"usuarioPadre":null,"nickname":null,"clave":null,"nombre":null,"apellidos":null,"isLoginWeb":null,"isLoginMovil":null,"estado":null,"correoElectronico":null,"imagePerfil":null,"perfil":null,"urlCambioClave":null,"telefono":null,"celular":null,"isFree":null,"proyectoUsuarioList":null,"cuentaActiva":null,"keyUser":null,"isCambiaPassword":null,"videoList":null,"idSocial":null,"tipoSocial":null,"idPlanActivo":null,"cantidadMbContratado":null,"cantidadMbConsumido":null,"cuotaMb":null,"fechaInicio":null,"fechaFin":null}"

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;

    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    @Path("/seguridad")
    public class SeguridadRest implements Serializable {



       @POST
        @Path("obtenerEntidad")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public JSONArray obtenerEntidad(Usuario u) {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            LOG.fatal(">>>Finally this is my entity(JPA/Hibernate) which 
will print the ID 99 as showed above :" + u.toString());
            return array;//this is empty

        }
       ..
```

Some tips : If you have problem with running the web after using this code may be because of the  `@Consumes in XML` ... you must set it as `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

Server Side:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addRecord(CustomClass mCustomClass)
{
    ///
    ///
    ///
    return "Added successfully : "+CustomClass.getName();

}// addRecord
```

Client Side:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ///
    ///
    ///
    CustomClass mCustomClass = new CustomClass();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String strResult = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(Entity.xml(mCustomClass), String.class);
}
```