# Restful Service for GET and PUT on XML as source?

Tags: web-services, rest

Is it possible to develop  Restful services for GET,PUT, POST and DELETE using an XML file as data source? I am using Netbeans 6.5.1 . Any references which I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can. You need to create a REST controller with the different REST methods (anotated with @GET, POST, ...). These methods will need to access the xml file. You should have a dedicated class for managing the file (with CRUD operations, etc.).

I think you can automatically generate your web service skeleton with netbeans but as it's not my IDE I am not sure. Anyway writing a REST resource is very simple. Look for Jersey examples as I guess  you will select this library.

Comment: Thanks. I have selected Jersey as the library but could not find any examples using XML. There are samples using database but not XML.

Comment: you just have to annotate your REST resources so that they accept/generate XML. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990988/passing-an-object-to-a-rest-web-service-using-jersey