# REST: GET returns UnsupportedMediaType

Tags: java, rest, request

I'm trying to `GET` data from Server via ReST. My server-side resource method looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public PersonRepresentation getPerson(@PathParam("id") @Nonnull final Long id) {

    // collect data
    // and return representation

    return personRepresentation;
}
```

The Class is defined like this:

```
@Path("person")
@Component
public class PersonResource {
}
```

Now I'm trying to make a simple `GET` on that resource:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/person/1234567890
Accept: application/xml
```

And this is what my server responded:

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
type: Status report
message: Unsupported Media Type

description: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format     
not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type).
```

Why I'm getting this error when I'm using the `GET`-Method. I think I've set the `Accept-Header` correct and used the `@Produces` in a way that's recommended. After googling around, I've found some "solutions" that say: you have to set the content-type of your request. But isn't it only necessary if I have a request-body ? (`POST & PUT`). Any ideas why I get the `Error-Code 415` ?

**edited**
This is what my tomcat console says:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.Long, and Java type class java.lang.Long, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
Feb 25, 2014 3:00:24 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
```

Answer (score 1):

Jersey only supports native types and `String`s. Change your `getPerson` function to the following and it should run:

```
public PersonRepresentation getPerson(@PathParam("id") final long id) {
```

If you really wish to pass in an object, another Stack Overflow question may have what you're looking for: [Passing an object to a REST Web Service using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1990988/899587)