# Invoking servlet through React app using Fetch API - Gives Failed to load Resource error (406 - Not Acceptable)

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, jersey, fetch-api

I'm very new to React JS and Java servlets. I have created a view in React and an API endpoint in servlet using Jersey. Both frontend and backend are run on a Tomcat server on my local machine. The servlet tries to access the service running at `http://localhost:37070/expenseClaimService/start` to post a new claim. This service is separately tested, and it returns the `id` of the new claim created.

Now I am trying to invoke the endpoint in servlet using `Fetch` from the React app. However I keep receiving `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406` in React app.

[image: error]

**The fetch call in React app**

```
  handleAddClaim = () => {
    console.log("in method");
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/eca/api/claims/new-claim", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "text/plain",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control_Allow-Orign": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        empName: "Test Vendor4",
        empFirstname: "Test",
        empLastname: "Vendor4",
        empEmail: "test4@mail.com",
        empId: "test3",
        empJobTitle: "SE",
        date: "08 December, 2018",
        refNo: "testRef999",
        memo: "OPD test claim 11",
        claims: [
          {
            amount: "9500.00",
            memo: "Test claim - Medicine",
            billDate: "4 December, 2018"
          }
        ]
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  };
```

**Endpoint in Servlet**

```
@Path("/claims")
public class OPDClaimEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Path("/new-claim")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String addNewClaim(JsonObject body){            
        return ExecutionUtils.generatePostRequest(body.toString());
    }
}
```

**Generating post request (using Apache HttpClient)**

```
public static String generatePostRequest(String input){
    String url = "http://localhost:37070/expenseClaimService/start";

    try {
        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(
                input,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.setEntity(requestEntity);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        return response.toString();
    }
    catch ( IOException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "Failed";
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>eca-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.org.eca.client.api.endpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>eca-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I solve this problem so that I can call the service from React app? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried both answers below (set `CONTENT-TYPE` in header and changed all input output types to `application/json`), now it gives 415 - Unsupported Media Type. It gives the same error when invoked in postman as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution!

In tomcat log files, it's seen that Jersey does not support JsonObject of Gson.

[image]

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872228/5802479) SO answer indicates, Jersey only supports native types and `String` as input in their methods. So I changed the endpoint method signature to take in Strings, `public String addNewClaim(String body)`, and now it works even with the bulky Json string. (Note that this is in Jersey 1.19, it may be different in Jersey 2.x). However it can take in Java objects as said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223061/5802479).

Answer (score 1):

You need to **send JSON** type, so replace ACCEPT with [CONTENT_TYPE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#CONTENT_TYPE)

```
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

With:

```
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

> The HTTP Content-Type header field name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you fetch call and the Servlet Endpoint, your `@Produces` annotations specifies that the servlet will produce "text/html" while the Fetch call specifies that it will only accept "text/plain" type ("Accept" header).

Try changing at least one of them (depending on what you need) to match each other and the problem should be fixed.